# Parse XML with modification blocks

Tags: xml

I have a strangely structured XML source file. This file contains information of various entities, and it is constantly updated. However, instead of providing a newer version of changed entity, this XML file keeps the modifications. Let me explain by example.
Say we have an original entity node

```
<identity ssid="1">
 <name>
  <value>Lukashenka</value>
 </name>
</identity>
```

later changed to

```
<identity ssid="1">
 <name>
  <value>Lukashenko</value>
 </name>
</identity>
```

In this XML, it will look like

```
<identity ssid="1">
 <name>
  <value>Lukashenka</value>
 </name>
</identity>
<modification>
 <removed>
  <identity ssid="1">
   <name>
    <value>Lukashenka</value>
   </name>
  </identity>
 </removed>
 <added>
  <identity ssid="1">
   <name>
    <value>Lukashenko</value>
   </name>
  </identity>
 </added>
</modification>
```

I never worked with this kind of format before and would like to change this xml file to a normal xml format so that I can import it into Excel.
I don't have a solid programming background, but if you are sure about the correct way to transform this file I wouldn't mind a try.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show your XML, instead of describing this in words.

Comment: Are there any other possible operations besides `add` and `removed`?

Comment: @potame thx for fixing the format :)

Comment: "I don't have a solid programming background" - what background do you have? I.e. any specific languages that you're familiar with or that you'd prefer the solution to be in?

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev as far as I see, only 'added' and 'removed'. Anyway I provide the source file here. http://www.seco.admin.ch/themen/00513/00620/index.html?lang=en
and the file is downloadable in "Overall list of sanctioned individuals, entities and organizations" section

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever VBA mainly. basic C, Python, javascript, java